# How can I get the pixels matrix of an image without using numpy?

Tags: image, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, python-imaging-library

I'd like to find a way of getting the pixels matrix without using `numpy`. I'm aware that using with the code

```
from PIL import Image  

import numpty as np  

img = Image.open('example.png', 'r')  

pixels = np.array(img)
```

`pixels`get the pixels matrix of the image. However, I'd like to find a way without using `numpy` to get the pixels image without using the package `numpy`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Image` methods [`getdata(band=None)`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) or [`getpixel(xy)`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpixel).

```
In [1]: from PIL import Image

In [2]: im = Image.open('block.png', 'r')

In [3]: data = list(im.getdata())

In [4]: data[:20]
Out[4]: 
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (144, 33, 33),
 (144, 33, 33),
 (144, 33, 33),
 (144, 33, 33),
 (255, 255, 255),
 (255, 255, 255),
 (255, 255, 255),
 (255, 255, 255),
 (0, 0, 0)]

In [5]: pxl = im.getpixel((1, 1))

In [6]: pxl
Out[6]: (144, 33, 33)
```

To convert the sequence returned by `getdata()` to a list of lists, you can use a list comprehension:

```
In [61]: data2d = [data[i:i+im.width] for i in range(0, len(data), im.width)]

In [62]: data2d[0]  # row 0
Out[62]: 
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0)]

In [63]: data2d[1]  # row 1
Out[63]: 
[(0, 0, 0),
 (144, 33, 33),
 (144, 33, 33),
 (144, 33, 33),
 (144, 33, 33),
 (255, 255, 255),
 (255, 255, 255),
 (255, 255, 255),
 (255, 255, 255),
 (0, 0, 0)]

In [64]: data2d[1][1]
Out[64]: (144, 33, 33)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But is it possible to get the matrix as a list of lists? I mean, the way `array(pixels)`does, since `list(im.getdata())`is just a list, isn't it?

Comment: I don't see an `Image` method for doing that automatically, but you can do it easily with standard python; see my updated answer.